# Why doesn't my Java array list implementation work properly

Tags: java

I'm trying to create three instances of an `ArrayList` called `checkout1`, `checkout2` and `checkout3`, but I'm having some issues. I try to call my method `customer1.Add()` and it doesn't work, and I cant figure out why.

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int MAX_SIZE = 100;
        CheckOut[] checkout1 = new CheckOut[MAX_SIZE];
        checkout1[0].AddCustomer(RandCustomer());
        System.out.println(checkout1.Size());
    }
    public static int RandCustomer(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int  items = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;
        return items;
    }
}


import java.util.*; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public class CheckOut {
    private ArrayList<Integer> customers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public void AddCustomer(int i){
        customers.add(i);
        return;
    }
    public int SizeCustomer(){
        return customers.size();
    }
}
```

Thanks. I have now fixed it, so it looks like this:

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int MAX_SIZE = 100;
        CheckOut[] checkout1 = new CheckOut[MAX_SIZE];
        checkout1[0] = new CheckOut();
        checkout1[0].AddCustomer(RandCustomer());
        System.out.println(checkout1[0].SizeCustomer());
    }
    public static int RandCustomer(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int  items = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;
        return items;
    }
}

import java.util.*; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public class CheckOut {
    private ArrayList<Integer> customers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public void AddCustomer(int i){
        customers.add(i);
        return;
    }
    public int SizeCustomer(){
        return customers.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you wanted to write `checkout1[0].Size()` when printing the size?

Comment: You should avoid saying "it doesn't work", instead explain what happens, and what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    CheckOut[] checkout1 = new CheckOut[MAX_SIZE];
    checkout1[0].AddCustomer(RandCustomer());
```

You forgot to create an instance of `CheckOut` and assign it to `checkout1[0]`. Therefore, you are probably getting a `NullPointerException`.

Change it to :

```
    CheckOut[] checkout1 = new CheckOut[MAX_SIZE];
    checkout1[0] = new CheckOut();
    checkout1[0].AddCustomer(RandCustomer());
```

Comment: There is no method called Size in Checkout class.

Comment: I meant even if OP does as you said, he wont be able to run the code and he will end up getting compilation issue.

Comment: Thanks, im trying to create three checkouts where customers choose a checkout based on shortest time wait, each customer gets generated with a random number of items as well, do you think im going along the right lines?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create some CheckOut objects.

This line

```
CheckOut[] checkout1 = new CheckOut[MAX_SIZE];
```

Creates an array that can contain references to Checkout objects, but currently
all those references are null references.

You can initialize your array by creating some new Checkout objects:

```
for (int i = 0; i < checkout1.length; i++) {
   checkout1[i] = new Checkout();
}
```

Comment: There is no method called Size in Checkout class.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of issues:

- You defined the array initialised it, but you never initialised Checkout object before using it. So you should do something like:

  ```
  CheckOut[] checkout1 = new CheckOut[MAX_SIZE]; 
  checkout1[0] = new CheckOut();
  checkout1[0].AddCustomer(RandCustomer());
  ```
- In your checkout class, you defined SizeCustomer method and you are trying to access like:

  System.out.println(checkout1.Size());

Which is wrong and compiler wont be happy with that. You should call it like:

```
System.out.println(checkout1.SizeCustomer());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have create array of `CheckOut`, the initial values are `null`, so you need to loop on all instance of this array to create instance before calling its metods as the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < checkout1.length; i++) {
  checkout1[i] = new Checkout();
}
```